# is there a better way then nested loops?

Tags: swift, swift3

I have the following code:

```
(0...engine.rows-1).forEach {row in
        (0...engine.cols-1).forEach {col in
            //print("(\(row),\(col)) state = \(engine.grid[(row,col)])")
            switch engine.grid[(row,col)] {
            case CellState.empty: emptyCount = emptyCount + 1
            case CellState.alive: aliveCount = aliveCount + 1
            case CellState.died: diedCount = diedCount + 1
            case CellState.born: bornCount = bornCount + 1
            }
        }
    }
```

It looks like filters could do this more efficiently but I don't understand the syntax for a complex object. If not filters is there a better way to do nested loops in swift?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: `(0...engine.rows-1)` is better written as `(0..<engine.rows)`

Comment: What is `engine`?  It is clearly not a standard Swift structure.  Does engine provide a way to get all cells or an enumerator for the cells?  What is wrong with nested loops?  They're a time proven way to walk a 2-D structure.

Comment: I thought there might be a way to use filter instead but it sounds like there is not.

Comment: Sorry didn't respond to first two questions. I am trying to get a count of each cell state in my grid which is really just and array with some properties. I know filters can produce an array that match a certain criteria. I thought I could do that and use count of the resulting filter.
Thanks for pointing out a better way to represent the range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life).

You are looping through a grid counting the various cell states.  Nested loops is the natural way to do this.  I would suggest using `for in` instead of `forEach`.  Also, I would suggest creating a dictionary to hold the counts:

```
// Create dictionary to hold counts
var counts: [CellState : Int] = [.alive: 0, .died: 0, .born: 0, .empty: 0]

for row in 0 ..< engine.rows {
    for col in 0 ..< engine.cols {
        //print("(\(row),\(col)) state = \(engine.grid[(row,col)])")
        counts[engine.grid[(row, col)]] += 1
    }
}
```

---

**Another way:**

You've given us no information on your `Engine` `class` or `struct`.  Depending on the implementation of `grid`, there might be a way to get an array of all of the cells.

For instance, if you use [N-Dimensional Array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51448698/1630618) to create the `grid`, then you can get all of the cells as an array with `grid.data`.

```
struct Engine {
    let rows: Int
    let cols: Int
    var grid: NDimArray<CellState>

    init(rows: Int, cols: Int) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        self.grid = NDimArray<CellState>(dimensions: rows, cols, initial: CellState.empty)
    } 
}
```

Setting a cell state would look like:

```
var engine = Engine(rows: 20, cols: 20)
engine.grid[0, 0] = .alive
engine.grid[0, 1] = .alive
```

Then the code to count the cells types becomes:

```
var counts: [CellState : Int] = [.alive: 0, .died: 0, .born: 0, .empty: 0]
engine.grid.data.forEach { cell in counts[cell] += 1 }
```

Comment: It is Game of Life. I have a class on swift and have been struggling with closures, etc. I was worried that I was defaulting back to a non-Swift way of programming.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer (just a minute ago).

Comment: A much better solution. Thanks!